# Regex match word without the prefix \ suffix i.e {{\w+}} without the curly brakets

Tags: c#, regex

The pattern `{{\w+}}` will match any word that is enclosed with double curly braces.

I want to match only the word inside without the braces

Comment: Could you explain more? Match how? For replace? For extraction?

Comment: You do not need to complicate the solution with lookarounds, it is much easier with capturing groups, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475547/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
(?<={{)\w+(?=}})
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGI4mV/1), [online compiler](https://ideone.com/HkEm3c)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to capture what `\w+` matches, use a capturing group:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"{{(\w+)}}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/towvSX)

Answer (score 0):

```
[^{{]\w+[^}}]
```

This regex should suffice - you are negating the `{{` and `}}` checks with `^`

Comment: This only works assuming the string is literally just `{{something}}` and that the user isn't trying to find all occurrences of `{{something}}` and determine what `something` is

Comment: True, good point.  I guess lacking context sort of bit me here.

Comment: It definitely is. The OP never stated anything other than what you presented an answer for, therefore it is still correct, but may be misleading due to the OP's improper explanation